# Get a truly RANDOM row from a PostgreSQL table quickly

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-performance, random

I always used to do:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

For large tables, this was unbearably, impossibly slow, to the point of being useless in practice. That's why I started hunting for more efficient methods. People recommended:

```
SELECT column FROM table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1) LIMIT 1;
```

While fast, it also provides worthless randomness. It appears to always pick the same damn records, so this is also worthless.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT column FROM table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(100) LIMIT 1;
```

It gives *even worse* randomness. It picks the same few records every time. This is completely worthless. I need actual randomness.

Why is it apparently so difficult to just pick a random record? Why does it have to grab EVERY record and then sort them (in the first case)? And why do the "TABLESAMPLE" versions just grab the same stupid records all the time? Why aren't they random whatsoever? Who would ever want to use this "BERNOULLI" stuff when it just picks the same few records over and over? I can't believe I'm still, after all these years, asking about grabbing a random record... it's one of the most basic possible queries.

What is the actual command to use for grabbing a random record from a table in PG which isn't so slow that it takes several full seconds for a decent-sized table?

Answer (score 15):

Interesting question - which has many possibilities/permutations (this answer has been extensively revised).

Basically, this problem can be divided into two main streams.

- A single random record
- Multiple random records (not in the question - see reference and discussion at bottom)

Having [researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql) this, I believe that the fastest solution to the single record problem is via the [`tsm_system_rows`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tsm-system-rows.html) extension to PostgreSQL provided by Evan Carroll's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/41337788#41337788).

If you're using a binary distribution, I'm not sure, but I think that the [`contrib`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/contrib.html) modules (of which `tsm_system_rows` is one) are available by default - at least they were for the [EnterpriseDB Windows](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) version I used for my `Windows` testing (see below). My main testing was done on 12.1 compiled from source on `Linux` (`make world` and `make install-world`).

The reason why I feel that it is best for the single record use case is that the only problem mentioned concerning this extension is that:

> Like the built-in SYSTEM sampling method, SYSTEM_ROWS performs
>   block-level sampling, so that the sample is not completely random but
>   may be subject to clustering effects, especially if only a small
>   number of rows are requested.

however, since you are only interested in selecting 1 row, the block-level clustering effect should not be an issue. [This article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/) from 2ndQuadrant shows why this shouldn't be a problem for a sample of **one** record! It is a **major** problem for small subsets (see end of post) - **OR** if you wish to generate a large sample of random records from one large table (again, see the discussion of `tsm_system_rows` and `tsm_system_time` below).

Then I created and populated a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rand AS SELECT generate_series(1, 100000000) AS seq, MD5(random()::text);
```

So, I now have a table with 100,000,000 (100 million) records. Then I added a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE rand ADD PRIMARY KEY (seq);
```

So, now to `SELECT` random records:

```
SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
```

Notice that I have used a slightly modified command so that I could "see" the randomness - I also set the `\timing` command so that I could get empirical measurements.

I used the [`LENGTH()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-length-function/) function so that I could readily perceive the size of the `PRIMARY KEY` integer being returned. Here is a sample of records returned:

```
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 970749.61 | bf18719016ff4f5d16ed54c5f4679e20
(1 row)

Time: 30.606 ms
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 512101.21 | d27fbeea30b79d3e4eacdfea7a62b8ac
(1 row)

Time: 0.556 ms
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 666476.41 | c7c0c34d59229bdc42d91d0d4d9d1403
(1 row)

Time: 0.650 ms
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column? |               md5                
--------+----------+----------------------------------
      5 | 49152.01 | 0a2ff4da00a2b81697e7e465bd67d85c
(1 row)

Time: 0.593 ms
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column? |               md5                
--------+----------+----------------------------------
      5 | 18061.21 | ee46adc96a6f8264a5c6614f8463667d
(1 row)

Time: 0.616 ms
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 691962.01 | 4bac0d051490c47716f860f8afb8b24a
(1 row)

Time: 0.743 ms
```

So, as you can see, the `LENGTH()` function returns 6 most of the time - this is to be expected as most records will be between 10,000,000 and 100,000,000, but there are a couple which show a value of 5 (also have seen values of 3 & 4 - data not shown).

Now, notice the timings. The first is 30 milliseconds (ms) but the rest are sub millisecond (approx. 0.6 - 0.7ms). **Most** of the random samples are returned in this sub-millisecond range, but, there are results returned in 25 - 30 ms (1 in 3 or 4 on average).

From time to time, this multi-millisecond result can occur twice or even three times in a row, but, as I said, the **majority** of results (approx. 66 - 75%) are sub-millisecond. **None** of the response times for my solution that I have seen has been in excess of 75ms.

During my research I also discovered the [`tsm_system_time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tsm-system-time.html) extension which is similar to `tsm_system_rows`. Now, I also benchmarked this extension as follows:

```
SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_TIME(0.001) LIMIT 1;
```

Note that the time quantum is 1/1000th of a millisecond which is a microsecond - if any number lower than this is entered, no records are returned. However, interestingly, even this tiny quantum **always** returns 120 rows.

Quite why it's 120 is a bit above my pay grade - the [PostgreSQL page size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239920/34007) is 8192 (the default)

```
test=# SELECT current_setting('block_size');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 8192
(1 row)
```

and the [`file system block size`](https://www.linuxnix.com/find-block-size-linux/) is 4096

```
[pol@UNKNOWN inst]$blockdev --getbsz /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home 
4096
```

A record should be (1 `INTEGER` (4 bytes) + 1 `UUID` (16 bytes)) (= 20 bytes) + the index on the `seq` field (size?). 4096/120 = 34.1333... - I hardly think that each index entry for this table takes 14 bytes - so where the 120 comes from, I'm not sure.

I'm not quite sure if the `LIMIT` clause will **always** return the first tuple of the page or block - thereby introducing an element of non-randomness into the equation.

The performance of the `tsm_system_time` query is identical (AFAICS - data not shown) to that of the `tsm_system_rows` extension. The same caveat about not being sure whether there is an element of non-randomness introduced by how these extensions choose their first record also applies to the `tsm_system_rows` queries. See discussion and bench-testing of the (so-called) randomness of these two methods below.

With respect to performance, just for reference, I'm using a Dell Studio 1557 with a 1TB HDD (spinning rust) and 8GB of DDR3 RAM running Fedora 31). This is a 10 year old machine!

I also did the same thing on a machine (Packard Bell, EasyNote TM - also 10 years old, 8GB DDR3 RAM running Windows 2019 Server) that I have with an SSD (SSD not top of the range by any means!) and the response times are typically (strangely enough) a bit higher (~ 1.3 ms), but there are  fewer spikes and the values of these are lower (~ 5 - 7 ms).

There could well be a lot of stuff running in the background with 2019 Server - but if you have a modern laptop with a decent SSD, there's no reason that you can't expect sub-millisecond response times as a matter of course!

All tests were run using PostgreSQL 12.1.

To check out the true "randomness" of both methods, I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE rand_samp 
(
  seq INT, 
  md5 TEXT
);
```

and then ran (3 times each):

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
  i RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO rand_samp (seq, md5)
    SELECT seq, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);  
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

and also using (in the inner loop of the above function)

```
SELECT seq, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_TIME(0.001) LIMIT 1;
```

Then after each run, I queried my `rand_samp` table:

```
SELECT 
  seq, COUNT(seq) 
FROM rand_samp 
GROUP BY seq 
HAVING COUNT(seq) > 1;
```

And got the following counts:

For `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS`, I got 258, 63, 44 dupes, **all** with a count of 2. For `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_TIME`, I got 46, 54 and 62, again **all** with a count of 2.

Now, my stats are a bit rusty, but from a random sample of a table of 100M records,from a sample of 10,000, (1 ten-thousandth of the number of records in the `rand` table), I'd expect a couple of duplicates - maybe from time to time, but **nothing** like the numbers I obtained. Furthermore, if there was true randomness, I'd expect (a small number of) 3's and 4's also.

I ran two tests with 100,000 runs using `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS` and obtained 5540 dupes (~ 200 with 3 dupes and 6 with 4 dupes) on the first run, and 5465 dupes on the second (~ 200 with 3 and 6 with 4). The **most** interesting query was this however:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.seq)
FROM rand_samp s
WHERE s.seq IN (SELECT sb.seq FROM rand_samp_bis sb);
```

where I compare dupes in both runs of 100,000 with respect to each other - the answer is a whopping 11,250 (> 10%) are the same - which for a sample of 1 thousandth (1/1000) is **WAY** to much to be down to chance!

Results 100,000 runs for `SYSTEM_TIME` - 5467 dupes, 215 with 3, and 9 with 4 on the first group, 5472, 210 (3) and 12 (4) with the second. The number of matching records is 11,328 (again > 10%).

There's clearly (**a LOT of**) non-random behaviour going on. I'll leave it to the OP to decide if the speed/random trade-off is worth it or not!

## Benchmark of other answers.

I decided to benchmark the other proposed solutions - using my 100 million record table from above. I ran all tests 5 times - ignoring any outliers at the beginning of any series of tests to eliminate cache/whatever effects. All the outlier values were higher than those reported below.

I'm using the machine with the HDD - will test with the SSD machine later. The `.mmm` reported means milliseconds - not significant for any answer but my own.

### [Daniel Vérité](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259207/34007)'s answer:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT seq FROM rand TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1)) AS s
 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Ran 5 times - all times were over a minute - typically 01:00.mmm (1 at 01:05.mmm).

Typical run:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT seq FROM rand TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1)) AS s
 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
   seq   
---------
 9529212
(1 row)

Time: 60789.988 ms (01:00.790)
```

### [Swav](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259208/34007)'s answer:

```
SELECT md5 FROM rand OFFSET (
    SELECT floor(random() * (SELECT count(seq) from rand))::int
) limit 1;
```

Ran 5 times - all times were over a minute - from 01:03 to 01:29

Typical run:

```
test=# SELECT md5 FROM rand OFFSET (
    SELECT floor(random() * (SELECT count(seq) from rand))::int
) limit 1;
               md5                
----------------------------------
 8004dfdfbaa9ac94243c33e9753e1f77
(1 row)

Time: 68558.096 ms (01:08.558)
```

### [Colin 't Hart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259211/34007)'s answer:

```
select * from rand where seq >= (
  select random()*(max(seq)-min(seq)) + min(seq) from rand
)
order by seq
limit 1;
```

Ran 5 times - times varied between 00:06.mmm and 00:14.mmm (Best of the Rest!)

Typical run:

```
test=# select * from rand where seq >= (
  select random()*(max(seq)-min(seq)) + min(seq) from rand
)
order by seq
limit 1;
   seq    |               md5                
----------+----------------------------------
 29277339 | 2b27c594f65659c832f8a609c8cf8e78
(1 row)

Time: 6944.771 ms (00:06.945)
```

### [Colin 't Hart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259211/34007)'s 2nd answer (adapted by me):

```
WITH min_max AS MATERIALIZED -- or NOT, doesn't appear to make a difference
(
  SELECT MIN(seq) AS min_s, MAX(seq) AS max_s, (MAX(seq) - MIN(seq)) - MIN(seq) AS diff_s
  FROM rand
),
other  AS MATERIALIZED
(
  SELECT FLOOR(RANDOM() * (SELECT diff_s FROM min_max))::INT AS seq_val
)
SELECT seq, md5 
FROM rand
WHERE seq = (SELECT seq_val FROM other);
```

Response time is between ~ 30 - 45ms with the odd outlier on either side of those times - it can even drop to 1.xxx ms from time to time. All I can really say is that it appears to be more consistent than either of the `SYSTEM_TIME` and `SYSTEM_ROWS` methods.

There is a **major** problem with this method however. If the underlying field that one is choosing for randomness is sparse, then this method won't return a value all of the time - this **may** or **may not** be acceptable to the OP? You can do something like (end of query):

```
SELECT seq, md5 
FROM rand
WHERE seq >= (SELECT seq_val FROM other)
LIMIT 1;
```

(note `>=` and `LIMIT 1`). This can be very efficient, (1.xxx ms), but seems to vary more than just the `seq =...` formulation - but once the cache appears to be warmed up, it regularly gives response times of ~ 1.5ms.

Another advantage of this solution is that it **doesn't** require any special extensions which, depending on the context (consultants not being allowed install "special" tools, DBA rules...) may not be available.

One **really WEIRD** thing about the above solution is that if the `::INT` CAST is removed, the query takes ~ 1 minute. This happens even though the [`FLOOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-math.html) function should return an `INTEGER`. I only discovered that this was an issue by running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE BUFFERS)`.

With ::INT

```
   CTE other
     ->  Result  (cost=0.02..0.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=38.906..38.907 rows=1 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
           InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
             ->  CTE Scan on min_max  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=38.900..38.902 rows=1 loops=1)
                   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
   InitPlan 6 (returns $5)
     ->  CTE Scan on other  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=38.909..38.910 rows=1 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
 Planning Time: 0.329 ms
 Execution Time: 68.449 ms
(31 rows)

Time: 99.708 ms
test=#
```

Without ::INT

```
   CTE other
     ->  Result  (cost=0.02..0.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.082..0.082 rows=1 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=10
           InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
             ->  CTE Scan on min_max  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=1 loops=1)
                   Buffers: shared hit=10
   InitPlan 6 (returns $5)
     ->  CTE Scan on other  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.085..0.085 rows=1 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=10
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rand  (cost=0.00..1458334.00 rows=208333 width=37) (actual time=52644.672..60025.906 rows=0 loops=3)
         Filter: ((seq)::double precision = $5)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 33333333
         Buffers: shared hit=14469 read=818865
 Planning Time: 0.378 ms
 Execution Time: 60259.401 ms
(37 rows)

Time: 60289.827 ms (01:00.290)
test=#
```

Note the (without `::INT`)

```
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rand  (cost=0.00..1458334.00 rows=208333 width=37) (actual time=52644.672..60025.906 rows=0 loops=3)
         Filter: ((seq)::double precision = $5)
```

Parallel Seq Scan (with a high cost), filter on (seq)::double

(**WHY double??**).

And

```
Buffers: shared hit=14469 read=818865
```

compared to (with `::INT`)

```
Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
```

### Finally, my own answer again (same machine, time & cache):

(this is now redundant in the light of the benchmarking performed above).

Ran my own benchmark again 15 times - typically times were sub-millisecond with the occasional (approx. 1 in 3/4) run taking approx. 25 milliseconds.

Typical run:

```
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 401578.81 | 30ff7ecfedea088dab75932f0b1ea872
(1 row)

Time: 0.708 ms
```

So, it would appear that my solution's worst times are ~ 200 times faster than the fastest of the rest of the pack's answers (Colin 't Hart).

My analysis is that there is **no** perfect solution, but the best one appears to be the adaptation of Colin 't Hart's solution.

Finally, a **GRAPHIC** demonstration of the problem associated with using this solution for more than one record is shown below - taking a sample of 25 records (performed several times - typical run shown).

The [tsm_system_rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tsm-system-rows.html) method will produce 25 sequential records. This may be suitable for certain purposes where the fact that the random sample is a number of sequential records isn't a problem, but it's definitely worth keeping in mind.

```
test=# SELECT LENGTH((seq/100)::TEXT), seq/100::FLOAT, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(25);
 length | ?column?  |               md5                
--------+-----------+----------------------------------
      6 | 763140.01 | 7e84b36ab30d3d2038ebd832c241b54d
      6 | 763140.02 | a976e258f6047df18e8ed0559ff48c36
--
--    SEQUENTIAL values of seq!
--
      6 | 763140.23 | ad4f1b4362187d6a300aaa9aaef30170
      6 | 763140.24 | 0c7fcc4f07d27fbcece68b2503f28d88
      6 | 763140.25 | 64d4507b18b5481a724d8a5bb6ac59c8
(25 rows)
```

Time: 29.348 ms

A similar state of affairs pertains in the case of the `SYSTEM_TIME` method. As mentioned above, even with a minimum time of 1μs, it gives 120 records. Just as with `SYSTEM_ROWS`, these give sequential values of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
test=# SELECT seq, md5 FROM rand TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_TIME(0.001);
```

returns:

```
   seq    |               md5                
----------+----------------------------------
 42392881 | e92f15cba600f0c7aa16db98c0183828
 42392882 | 93db51ea870e15202144d11810c8f40c
 42392883 | 7357bf0cf1fa23ab726e642832bb87b0
 42392884 | 1f5ce45fb17c8ba19b391f9b9c835242
 42392885 | f9922b502d4fd9ee84a904ac44d4e560
 ...
 ...  115 sequential values snipped for brevity!
```

Our sister site, StackOverflow, treated this very issue [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql). Good answers are provided by (yet again) Erwin Brandstetter [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675160/470530) and Evan Carroll [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337788/470530). That whole thread is worth reading in detail - since there are different definitions of `random` (monotonically increasing/decreasing, [`Pseudorandom number generators`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)...) and `sampling` (with or without replacement...).

Comment: For `tsm_system_rows` to produce a single *truly* random row, all data pages (blocks) have to contain the exact same number of tuples. Even if all rows have the exact same size and there are no dead tuples at all, the last data page is typically not filled completely, which gives contained rows a (much) higher chance to be picked. So while `tsm_system_rows` is fast, and may be good enough for many purposes, it's hardly ever *truly* random, even for just a single row.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is to always take the first row of the sample.

Take a random row instead:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT column FROM table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1)) AS s
 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

The contents of the sample is random but the order in the sample is not random. Since the sampling does a table scan, it tends to produce rows in the order of the table. This is obvious if you look at a freshly created, perfectly ordered table:

```
create table a as select * from generate_series(1,1000000) as i;

select * from a tablesample bernoulli(1) limit 10;
  i   
------
  248
  394
  463
  557
  686
  918
  933
 1104
 1124
 1336
(10 rows)
```

Applying LIMIT directly to the sample tends to produce always small values, from the beginning of the table in its order on disk. This is worse with LIMIT 1.

Now compare this to the correct method:

```
select * from (select * from a tablesample bernoulli(1) ) s order by random() limit 10;
   i    
--------
 622931
 864123
 817263
 729949
 748422
 127263
 322338
 900781
  49371
 616774
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that might work for you if you (can) have (mostly) sequential IDs and have a primary key on that column:

First find the minimum and maximum ID values. This will use the index.

Then generate a random number between these two values.

Finally, select the first row with ID greater or equal that random value. This will also use the index.

The query will look something like:

```
select * from mytable where id >= (
  select random()*(max(id)-min(id))+min(id) from mytable
)
order by id
limit 1;
```

Tested on Postgres 12 -- insert explain analyze to view the execution plan if you like:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ede64b836e76259819c10cb6aecc7c84

**UPDATE**

In response to @Vérace's benchmarking, I did some testing. While the version on DB Fiddle seemed to run fast, I also had problems with Postgres 12.1 running locally.

In response to this, I made two changes:

1. I replaced the `>=` operator with an `=` on the `round()` of the sub-select.
2. I split the query into two... maybe against the rules?

```
colin=> select round(random()*(max(seq)-min(seq)) + min(seq)) from rand;
  round   
----------
  23656425
(1 row)

Time: 0,394 ms
colin=> select * from rand where seq = 23656425;
   seq    |               md5                
----------+----------------------------------
 23656425 | ba9777a8a6e14e3ce21d55c7f6089fe5
(1 row)

Time: 99,307 ms
colin=>
```

Now I get a time around 100ms. I will keep fiddling to see if I can combine the two queries, or where it goes wrong. I suspect it's because the planner doesn't know the value coming from the sub-select, but with an `=` operator it should be planning to use an index scan, it seems to me?

Comment: Selecting *the first row with ID greater or equal that random value* is not exactly random, as IDs after gaps have a size-of-gap times greater chance to be picked.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT column FROM table OFFSET (
    SELECT floor(random() * (SELECT count(id) from table))::int
) limit 1;
```

Important thing to note is that you need an index on the table to ensure it doesn't use sequential scan. Add `explain plan` in front of the quuery and check how it would be executed.

---

I have done some further testing and this answer is indeed slow for larger data sets (>1M). It has two main time sinks:

- `explain analyze SELECT count(*) from rand;` about 30s for 100M records
- selecting row with offset varies depending on which row selected, if selecting last row it takes a minute to get there.

Putting above together gives 1min 30s that @Vérace seen in his benchmark.

Comment: I benchmarked your answer compared to mine (see end of my [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259210/34007)) and it would appear that your solution takes quite a long time (> 1 min).  I wonder if you would care to comment and/or correct/change my benchmark in the interests of giving every answer the best possible chance. p.s welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make your sample size as close to "1 row" as possible by specifying a smaller sample percentage (you seem to assume that it has to be an integer value, which is not the case). For example, for a table with 10K rows you'd do `select something from table10k tablesample bernoulli (0.02) limit 1`.

Note that if you pick a sample percentage that's too small the probability of the sample size to be less than 1 increases.

For a *really* large table you'd probably want to use `tablesample system`.

Comment: If you can tolerate the bias introduced by SYSTEM, then https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tsm-system-rows.html is probably better as you can specify the sample size in rows rather than as a percentage.

Comment: @Vérace the `system` sampling might be suitable for a 100M rows table, but not for 100K rows. We don't know the details, as the OP seems to be more interested in venting his frustration rather than finding a solution to the [unknown] problem.

Comment: @mustaccio [This](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/) (2nd Quadrant are always good) gives an outline of how the randomness of the two sampling methods, SYSTEM and BERNOULLI, works. But, in this particular case, where the OP just wants 1 random record, the block/page level sampling problem with the SYSTEM method isn't an issue - a random record is chosen from a random block! I understand that if you want a sample of, say, 15% the BERNOULLI method is superior but performance suffers (a lot). COUNT(x) solutions are also poor (at least for 10^8 records).